# login.php, retrieving and matching password not work

Tags: php

I have a `Login.php` page that retrieves and matches the `email address` and `password` for the registered users like this:

```
<?php # login.php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
// Initialize an error array.
$errors = array();

//Flag variables
$e = $p = FALSE;

// Trim all the incoming data:
$trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);

//Validate the email
if (!empty($trimmed['email'])) {
    $e = $trimmed['email'];
} else {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address!';
}

// Validate the password:
if (!empty($trimmed['pass'])) {
    $p = $trimmed['pass'];  

} else {
    $errors[]= 'You forgot to enter your password!';
}

if ($e && $p) { //OK

$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";     

//Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);

    //Bind the parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email) ;

    //Assign values to variables
    $email = $e;  

    //Execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();

    //Store the statement
    $stmt->store_result();

    $row_cnt = $stmt->num_rows;

        echo $row_cnt;

}else{// If everything wasn't OK.
    foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error.
        echo "- $msg<br />\n";
        }
            echo 'Please try again!';

}//end of IF($e && $p)
}
?>

<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">

<fieldset>
    <p><b>Email</b><input type="email" name="email" ></p>
    <p><b>Password</b><input type="password" name="pass"> </p>

</fieldset>
<p><input type="submit"  value="Login" id="submit"></p>
```

**Everything goes well**. However, if I add the `pass`check into **WHERE** in the `select query`like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pass =?";

//Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);

    //Bind the parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $pass) ;

    //Assign values to variables
    $email = $e;
    $pass = SHA1('$p');
```

The `$row_cnt` always returns 0, even though the password i submitted is either matched with the one in the `users` table in the database or not.

What did I do wrong,please? Did I assign the correct value for the `$pass` variable, or what else?

**NOTE**: I applied `$pass = SHA1('$p');` during registration process.

Comment: can you please try                                                                                      //Bind the parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, SHA1($pass)) ;

Comment: i think the issue is, replace $pass = SHA1('$p'); with     $pass = SHA1($p); and see,

Comment: Already tried! without the `pass` variable checking, it echoes/returns 1, otherwise, it returns 0. That's why I ask this question for help!

Comment: `'$p'` is literally the string '$p'. If you mean to use the variable, use the variable (without quotes).

Comment: Obvious question: are passwords stored as SHA1 hash in the database...?!

Comment: *"I applied `$pass = SHA1('$p');` during registration process."* – So all hashes in the database are the same, the hash value of the string "$p"? – Do some simple debugging by outputting the hash value you're trying to query and see whether that value exists in your database.

Comment: @deceze: you're correct! It works for me now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be the use of single quotes for variable replacement, as seen in this line:

```
$pass = SHA1('$p');
```

PHP doesn't replace the content of the variable when you use single quotes, so this line actually means a string with the value `$p`. You either have to use double quotes

```
$pass = SHA1("$p");
```

or just use the variable directly

```
$pass = SHA1($p);
```

Comment: Wow, my mistake! Thanks!